# MySQL One-To-Many SUM of COUNTs

Tags: mysql, join, count, one-to-many

After 2 days of searching and trying similar questions, it's got to the point where I need to ask the question!

I have the following database structure (simplified)..

```
mt_product           | mt_sku                              | mt_price
==========           | ======                              | ========
id | brand_id | mpn  | id | product_id | retailer_id | sku | id | sku_id | price | date
```

For instance...
* A can of Coca-Cola is ONE product. 
* It can be sold in many different retailers, who will all have a SKU for it.
* This SKU will have a price, which can change day-by-day.

I want to list the total number of prices for the product.
To list this I currently have the following query which nearly works...

```
SELECT
p.id AS pid, p.title AS p_title, p.cat, p.mpn,
b.id AS bid, b.name AS brand,
(SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM mt_sku AS s WHERE s.pid = p.id) AS num_sku,
(SELECT COUNT(gbp.id) FROM mt_price AS gbp INNER JOIN mt_sku ON mt_sku.id = gbp.sid ) AS num_price
FROM mt_product AS p
INNER JOIN mt_brand b ON p.bid = b.id
INNER JOIN mt_sku s ON p.id = s.pid
```

num_sku returns as expected, however when I introduce the second sub query for num_price (and I have revised this many times) I either get...
* no duplications of the pid but the num_price is the total number of prices to SKUs, not the amount of prices for this product_id (as query above)
 [eg1_img](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg1.PNG)
* the correct number of num_price, but instead of totalling up the total num_price, the pid is duplicated in the table (as query below) - therefore as the pid is duplicated, this does not give me the result I want. I added DISTINCT as it helped an earlier version of the query, it now makes no difference.  [eg2_img](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg3.PNG)

```
SELECT
DISTINCT(p.id) AS pid, p.title AS p_title, p.cat, p.mpn,
b.id AS bid, b.name AS brand,
(SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM mt_sku AS s WHERE s.pid = p.id) AS num_sku,
(SELECT COUNT(gbp.id) FROM mt_price AS gbp WHERE s.id = gbp.sid) AS num_price
FROM mt_product AS p
INNER JOIN mt_brand b ON p.bid = b.id
INNER JOIN mt_sku s ON p.id = s.pid
```

I'm pretty sure the key to this is that
product can have multiple SKUs, of which a SKU has multiple price history.

Any help or ideas of the schema would be superb.

Comment: Add a short example containing 2-3 rows from each table and the expected result of the query; it will help us understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you...

The first query gives this - [link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg2.PNG)
The second query gives this - [link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg3.PNG)

Comment: The output of your queries doesn't help very much. Post the input data and the output you **expect**.

Comment: When I put the data retrieved in the table [link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg4.PNG) you will probably see a little better.

Both of the Odaban entries have been "opened up". These are actually the duplicate results from the query. When they are opened up, a separate query which gathers all the prices for the pid is fired (which successfully retrieves the prices and the date).

!!So!! This entry should read, # SKUs 5 (correct) and #prices 6. What it actually retrieves is a duplicate entry of Odaban and the amount of prices for one of the SKUs (not all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS pid, p.title AS p_title, p.cat, p.mpn,
  b.id AS bid, b.name AS brand,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) AS num_sku,
  COUNT(gbp.id) AS num_price
FROM mt_product AS p
  INNER JOIN mt_brand b ON p.brand_id = b.id
  INNER JOIN mt_sku s ON p.id = s.product_id
  INNER JOIN mt_price gbp ON s.id = gbp.sku_id
GROUP BY b.id, p.id
```

The products that don't have SKUs defined will not appear in the result set. Use `LEFT JOIN mt_sku` to make them appear in the result set (having `0` for `num_sku` and `num_price`):

```
  LEFT JOIN mt_sku s ON p.id = s.product_id
```

In both variants of the query, the products that do not have prices defined will not appear in the result set. Use `LEFT JOIN mt_price` to include them into the result set (having `0` for `num_price`):

```
  LEFT JOIN mt_price gbp ON s.id = gbp.sku_id
```

Take a look at the MySQL documentation for [`JOINs`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: I think we're getting close (many thanks again, this is a great community!) However, this only returns one row. [link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg5.PNG) - The two COUNTs return the total number rather than the amount for this one product.id ()pid). It needs to return all, I think subqueries are still the answer to this. I'm going to keep trying, but still, this is to no avail.

Comment: Nearly there! This query [link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg6.PNG) gives this [link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg7.PNG) - for the first time the total number of prices is correct. However, the pid is duplicated. If they were totalled up so pid only exists in the results once, then this has been cracked!

Comment: The correct counting of the SKUs requires using `DISTINCT`. I updated the code.

Comment: Fixed the code again. In the first version I forgot somehow to put the `GROUP BY` clause (probably I removed it by mistake). Now it should produce the results you need.

Comment: you beautiful, intelligent person. You have made my day. When I get a little more reputation on this site, I will upvote you. Thanks for taking your time on this, it is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the total prices then you need correlations.

Your first count is fine, because it is correlated to the outer query.  The second has no correlation, so that seems strange.  The following fixes the `num_price` subquery:

```
SELECT p.id AS pid, p.title AS p_title, p.cat, p.mpn,
       b.id AS bid, b.name AS brand,
       (SELECT COUNT(s2.id) FROM mt_sku s2 WHERE s2.pid = p.id) AS num_sku,
       (SELECT COUNT(gbp.id) FROM mt_price gbp WHERE s.id = gbp.sid ) AS num_price
FROM mt_product p INNER JOIN
     mt_brand b
     ON p.bid = b.id INNER JOIN
     mt_sku s
     ON p.id = s.pid;
```

I'm also not sure why you have all the joins in the outer query.  I assume that a given product is going to have multiple rows, and you want the multiple rows to have the same `num_sku` and `num_price` values.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.
I used the above but the query is back to repeating the pid's.

[link](http://mrflibble.xyz/img/qry_eg1.PNG)

Comment: There is no correlation because the one pid can have multiple SKUs, these SKUs can have multiple prices.

I want to count how many total prices there are. So, num_SKU correctly gets the amount of SKUs for the pid, however, the num_price with your example only gives the amount of price for that SKU id, not total up all of the SKUs and return one pid (see the link above for the result)

Comment: You should edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you, some images of the results have now been added to teh above.

You can see that the second query picture nearly gives the right results, but the 2nd and 3rd rows are separate. This is because one of the SKUs has 2 prices, another only has the 1 price.

I want all of the prices totalled together for all of the SKUs in the db.